# Validate form, Assign form input to strings and display them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, forms, validation

So I've been cracking at this code and can't figure out what's going on.

Basically, I must validate this form, and assign each input into a string, then display it later. Right now, I can't even grasp at the validation because it just won't work, when I click the "adicionar" button the page simply refreshes. It should show an alert if the forms are empty, and for the age input, it should alert if it's not numeric or if it's `<= 0`.

Here's the JavaScript and HTML:

```js
window.onload = function code(){
  

  function validarForm()
  {
    var company = document.getElementById('empresa').value;
    var name = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    var team = document.getElementById('time').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('idade').value;

    if (company == '' || company == null) {
      alert("O campo Empresa é obrigatório!");
      return false;
    }
    if (name == '') {
      alert("O campo Nome é obrigatório!");
      return false;
    }
    if (team == '') {
      alert("O campo Time é obrigatório!");
      return false;
    }
    if (isNaN(age) || age <= 0) {
      alert("Escreva um número maior que 0!");
      return false;
    }
  
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName("add").onclick = function() {validateForm()};
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cadastro de Desenvolvedores</title>
        <style>
            .debug {
                font-family: monospace;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Cadastros de desenvolvedores</h1>
        <div class="cadastro">
            <ol class="desenvolvedores"></ol>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Empresa
                        <input type="text" name="empresa">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Nome
                        <input type="text" name="nome">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Idade
                        <input type="text" name="idade">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Time
                        <select name="time">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <option value="front">Frontend</option>
                            <option value="back">Backend</option>
                            <option value="infra">Infraestrutura</option>
                            <option value="telecon">Telefonia</option>
                            <option value="outro">Outro</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Tecnologias
                        <select multiple name="tec">
                            <option value="js">Javascript</option>
                            <option value="php">PHP</option>
                            <option value="java">Java</option>
                            <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
                            <option value="python">Python</option>
                            <option value="perl">Perl</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Estágio?
                        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="add">adicionar</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <pre class="debug"></pre>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, something to note is that the assignment requires that the HTML file should not be changed directly (only being able to make changes via javascript), and no JavaScript libraries are allowed (not even jQuery). Sorry some of the code is not in English, because i'm Brazilian.

Comment: what about using google and search function? i know i have answered the question yesterday how to validate form fields. by the way. your if doesn't match if somebody puts in a space. your have to use trim and check the length of the trimmed string agains <= 0

Answer (score 1):

**getElementsByClassName** will return an array of items. change `class` to `id="add"` to get the click function to work

Answer (score 1):

OK. Where to start!
As Kody says, getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. As there is only one element with that class you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0].onclick = function() {return validarForm()};
```

also note that the function is validarForm() not validateForm() and you need to add "return" otherwise it will submit.

You can't use getElememtById to get the values of the textboxes as they don't have an Id set, just a name. so you would have to get the inputs using

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')
```

Note that this too returns an array of elements for you to work with.

Comment: Thank you. But now document.getElementsByTagName is always returning undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you repost your updated code and see where you have got to. Make sure that it is all spelt correctly etc.